# Building an Excel reporting and mailing web app

Tags: python, web-applications, frameworks, data-analysis, reporting

It's my first time using python, and I've got to build a reporting web app, where the user should be able to choose the info he wants from a very large database already existing and it's got to put the data in an Excel document that may be saved on the user's laptop and also be send via mail to a list of receivers that they've got to give to the app.

I'm really lost and don't know where to start, and my biggest problem is what framework shall I use?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well, I started building the app using Django as a framework but my colleague said that I should be using Dash, and now I don't know what to do since it's my very first time using python.